# How can I set up polyfills correctly so that my Vue.JS website works on Internet Explorer 11?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, webpack, internet-explorer-11, babel-polyfill

I have a project built with Laravel and Vue.JS (Using Bootstrap-Vue also). Everything works as it should on all browsers including Edge. But as you guessed it, not in IE11.

I have tried various configurations of using babel/polyfills.

In my **webpack.mix.js** I have the following code:

```
let mix = require('laravel-mix');

require('laravel-mix-polyfill');

mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
    .sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'public/css')
    .polyfill({
        enabled: true,
        useBuiltIns: "entry",
        targets: { "firefox": "50", "ie": 11 }
    });
```

I have the following dependencies in my **package.json** file:

```
"devDependencies": {
        "@babel/polyfill": "^7.8.3",
        "axios": "^0.18.1",
        "bootstrap": "^4.3.1",
        "cross-env": "^5.1",
        "laravel-mix": "^4.0.7",
        "laravel-mix-polyfill": "^1.1.1",
        "lodash": "^4.17.5",
        "mutationobserver-shim": "^0.3.3",
        "node-sass": "^4.13.1",
        "popper.js": "^1.12",
        "portal-vue": "^2.1.4",
        "resolve-url-loader": "^2.3.1",
        "sass": "^1.15.2",
        "sass-loader": "^7.1.0",
        "vue": "^2.6.10",
        "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.10"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "@chenfengyuan/vue-qrcode": "^1.0.1",
        "bootstrap-vue": "^2.2.0",
        "current-device": "^0.9.1",
        "intersection-observer": "^0.7.0",
        "lottie-vuejs": "0.3.6",
        "moment": "^2.24.0",
        "v-mask": "^2.0.2",
        "vue-autosuggest": "1.8.3",
        "vue-js-toggle-button": "^1.3.3",
        "vue-recaptcha": "^1.2.0",
        "vue-social-sharing": "^2.4.7",
        "vue2-flip-countdown": "^0.9.3",
        "vuelidate": "^0.7.4"
    }
```

And my **app.js** file has this at the top as recommended by Bootstrap-Vue documentation:

```
import '@babel/polyfill'
import 'intersection-observer' // Optional
```

I have also tried adding the script tag from polyfill.io in the head section of my website.

All result in a blank screen with a SCRIPT1002 Syntax Error and a SCRIPT5007 Object expected error. I'm not sure where I am going wrong, and I really need to get this to work for IE11 unfortunately. None of my Vue components are self-closing in the blade files as answered in a similar question here. And I'm not using Vue CLI.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So I decided to remove all components and plugins, to see if Vue and Bootstrap-Vue worked on their own in IE11. It worked fine and I was receiving the usual Vue dev message in the console.

I then added in each module one by one until the website no longer rendered in IE11. This only happened when **lottie-vuejs** was enabled, and upon inspecting the console a syntax error is shown (expecting a '}''.

So the reason my project was not working was due to this plugin.

Comment: Thanks for posting the solution to this issue. I suggest you try to mark your own answer as an accepted answer to this question after 48 hrs when it is available to mark. It can help other community members in the future in similar kinds of issues. Thanks for your understanding.